# Extract text from a file and save the results into a pipe-delimited file

Tags: ruby, regex

I am not a programmer, but I am taking a bioinformatics class as I'm a molecular genetics major... our assignment is to take a file of multiple entries like this:

> 77: XP_001929585
>   **PREDICTED: similar to BRCA1 associated protein** [**Sus scrofa**]
>   gi|**194042959**|ref|XP_001929585.1| [194042959]

and extract the items I've bolded, then save the results into a pipe-delimited file like this:

`194042959|Sus scrofa|PREDICTED: similar to BRCA1 associated protein.`

We are using the Sublime editor to write our scripts in Ruby. I know how to open the file and then... well, here's my script so far...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
File.open("mmg231_hw5_brca1.txt").each do |file_line|
  if file_line =~ /^(.+)\[([A-Z].+)\]/
    description = $1
    taxon_name = $2
    puts "#{taxon_name}|#{description}" 
  elsif file_line =~ /\[([0-9].+)\]/
    gi_number = $1
    puts "#{gi_number}"
  end
end
```

I know that it's wrong... the regular expressions do capture what they need to. the first puts does put out the taxon name and the description properly, but I can't figure out how to get the gi number in there too, as its on a different line... I can pull out the gi number on its own also, but have no way of linking it to the other two parts. Also, when I pull them out using the regular expressions I developed, they stay in the right order as they were in the file, so I was trying to think of a way to tell the computer to like number each taxon name/description pair 1, 2, 3, etc as in the file, and then do the same with the gi numbers, and then you could just say like taxon name/description 1 goes with gi number 1, etc... or have the computer get the taxon name and description pair, then just look in the next line for the gi number, but I don't know how to do this...

help? And in plain english would be helpful, most help sites I feel like I would be able to use, but I just don't understand the language...

first 4 entries:

```
1: ZP_00239925
BRCA1 [Bacillus cereus G9241]
gi|47569239|ref|ZP_00239925.1||gnl|WGS:NZ_AAEK|BCE_G9241_3679 [47569239]

2: NP_009225
breast cancer 1, early onset isoform 1 [Homo sapiens]
gi|6552299|ref|NP_009225.1| [6552299]

3: NP_033894
breast cancer 1 [Mus musculus]
gi|161016835|ref|NP_033894.3| [161016835]

4: NP_036646
breast cancer 1 [Rattus norvegicus]
gi|6978573|ref|NP_036646.1| [6978573]
```

Comment: I think that it would help if you showed more of the input file examples.

Comment: Can you please post example of `mmg231_hw5_brca1.txt` with 3 different entries? How big is your input file in megabytes and how big files will possibly be used as an input in the future?

Comment: I added the first 4 entries - there are 4328 of them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the lines always come in pairs?

If so, why not doing:

```
description = taxon_name = gi_number = nil
first = false
File.open("mmg231_hw5_brca1.txt").each do |file_line|

  if file_line =~ /^(.+)\[([A-Z].+)\]/    
    description = $1
    taxon_name = $2
    first = true #Just to check they are consecutive 
  else
    if file_line =~ /\[([0-9].+)\]/
      gi_number = $1
      if first == true
        puts "#{gi_number}|#{taxon_name}|#{description}"
      end
    end
    first = false
  end
end
```

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! If its not too much to ask, can you explain the logic behind what you did?

Comment: The problem you were facing was that you have part of the data in one line of the file and part at the following line. So, what I did was to keep the descriptio and taxon_name from the first line, add a boolean variable to indicate that the first line was read. Then the loop reads another line and I check if it matches the first line, it will not, if it matches the second I get the gi_number and print all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

http://ideone.com/MGW3Z

```
description, taxon_name = nil, nil

STDIN.each do |line|
  case line
  when /^(.+?\: .+) \[(.+?)\]$/
    description, taxon_name = $1, $2
  when /^.+?\|(\d+)\|\w+\|/
    gi_number = $1
    puts "#{gi_number}|#{taxon_name}|#{description}."
  end
end
```

I guess, if you hope accuracy and check "XP_001929585".